# Cannot flash Moto G3 2015 due to "Preflash validation failed" error

Tags: rom-flashing, bootloader-lock, motorola-moto-g3

I have a Moto G3 XT1550 phone. I had to reset the phone as its UI was restarting on its own after 1-2 minutes of usage. After the phone booted, it asked me to enter the GMail and password the phone was registered with which I did, but the phone failed to recognize the Google account credentials.

**I NEVER ACTIVATED USB DEBUGGING FROM DEVELOPER OPTIONS ON 'THIS' DEVICE AS I NEVER NEEDED TO.**

I performed "*Wipe data/factory reset"* and "*Wipe cache partition*" from **Recovery Mode** expecting that the stored Google account would be removed. But it did not. Then I came to know that it is called "Factory Reset Protection (FRP)".

Since then, I have tried everything I could find over the Internet - Bypassing FRP, flash Stock ROM (100% sure downloaded a correct one), flash custom ROM, and flash TWRP. All to no use. Even tried unlocking the bootloader (got the unlock code from Motorola's website the same). Even that did not work, saying:

```
C:\MotoG3>fastboot oem unlock XCYJ4AZH542XAQWBJYFF
...
(bootloader) Check 'Allow OEM Unlock' in Developer Options. FAILED (remote failure)
finished. total time: 0.016s
```

While flashing any image from fastboot, it keeps throwing a **Preflash validation failed** error.

```
C:\MotoG3>fastboot flash partition gpt.bin
target reported max download size of 268435456 bytes
sending 'partition' (32 KB)...
OKAY [  0.018s]
writing 'partition'...
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote failure)
```

---

```
C:\Moto G3\Mfastboot>fastboot flash recovery twrp-osprey-2.8.7-test1.img
target reported max download size of 268435456 bytes
sending 'recovery' (11170 KB)...
OKAY [  0.400s]
writing 'recovery'...
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote failure)
```

I've even tried an article that tells a trick to entering the phone's settings by long-pressing a word in the Privacy Policy of the phone and opening "Define". Long pressing on a word just makes the phone vibrate and not select it.

Even attaching an OTG drive with the hope to copy FRPBypass APK to the phone's memory work as nothing shows up on connecting the OTG drive (as against expected File Explorer opening up).

In a nutshell, I have kind-of soft-bricked my phone. Left with no other option. I don't even expect the Service Center guys to do anything that I haven't tried (expect to change the ROM chip, if ever possible).

Any help, please?

Comment: Preflash Validation Errors are because your device has a newer ROM or firmware than you are trying to install, downgrading is not supported. You cannot unlock the bootloader without enabling OEM Unlocking in Developer Options either. But your question isn't really about that is it? Flashing a new ROM will not remove FRP, there is currently no working bypass for FRP on any Moto G 2015 with a security update after about April-May of 2016.

Comment: The firmware ROM I am trying to flash is Marshmallow. And the firmware on my device is also Marshmallow. The difference might be in subversions. In that case, I am helpless. What about trying unofficial ROM's? Any ideas?

Comment: You have a locked bootloader, there is no way to flash custom recovery (required for custom ROMs) or any other package that is not digitally signed. Have you looked here for a newer factory image: https://forum.xda-developers.com/2015-moto-g/general/index-moto-g-factory-firmware-images-t3169639 ?

Comment: After going through the link you provided, it seems like I MUST wait for OFFICIAL Android N firmware from Motorola /Lenovo.

Comment: Be aware, none of this will allow you bypass Factory Reset Protection. Flashing a new ROM will NOT bypass this at all. At this time there is no way around FRP on the Moto G 2015 unless you have a device on an older ROM (which you obviously do not). There is no known way to remove or bypass FRP on this device and a new ROM will not help.

Comment: I don't care about whether FRP can be bypassed or not. In short, knowing the fact that my device is having Android 6; and that no official or unofficial ROM above Android 6 is available for this very model, what options do I have?

Comment: I'm confused... I thought the end result was to get around the FRP and have a working phone? Patience will likely yield a new enough ROM image appearing on XDA, but that might take days, weeks, or even months, we never know how quickly they can be acquired from Moto, especially since being absorbed by Lenovo, but the FRP will still be there even if/when we get that factory image. Otherwise with a locked bootloader your options are limited to Moto service to repair/reflash the device (they have a different way of doing it than you or I do).

Comment: Thanks ace for being with me in the discussion. I'll check with Motorola Service, if they can do anything about it